# RxJS custom operator doesn't call complete

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have the following custom operator:

```
export function test() {
  return function(source) {
    return new Observable(observer => {

      return source.subscribe({
        next(value) {
          observer.next(value);
        },
        error(error) {
          observer.error(error);
        },
        complete() {
          console.log('completed')
          observer.complete();
        }
      })
    });
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I subscribe to an observable that completes I didn't get to the complete callback, i.e I don't see the completed log.

```
interval(1000).pipe(
  test(),
  take(2)
).subscribe();
```

What am I missing?

Comment: That's because it passes the value to the `take` operator for each emitted value, That's why it's not calling complete. Try `take(2)` operator first and then your custom operator `test()`.

Comment: `take` completes upon the second `next` notification and it then unsubscribes. The observable returned from `test` does not complete; its subscriber - the `take`operator - unsubscribes and that is not the same as completion.

Comment: @cartant so if we need to do some cleanup we can use the finalize operator before subscribing to the source? (in the test operator)

Comment: The callback passed to `finalize` will be called upon completion, error or explicit unsubscription. You could also add a callback to the subscription you are returning from the observable you create in the `test` operator. See https://link.medium.com/JUIGbbevBX E.g. `subscription.add(() => /* whatever */);`

Comment: @cartant when I use your suggestion and add subscription.add(() => /* whatever */);   it doesn't call the callback when running my example. You could try it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

nice question, now lets dive in the explanation.

First, let's see the solution

```js
function test(limitter) {
  return function(source) {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      return source.subscribe({
        next(value) {
          observer.next(value);
        },
        error(error) {
          observer.error(error);
        },
        complete() {
          console.log("completed action");
          observer.complete("completed value");
        }
      });
    });
  };
}

interval(1000)
  .pipe(
    take(2),
    test()
  )
  .subscribe(
    x => {
      console.log("result: ", x);
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
    },
    end => {
      console.log("Observable has been completed");
    }
  );
```

So what's the difference, in this snippet the `take` operator is prior to the custom `test()` operator, which means that whenever we hit the desired count (in our case `2`),  the `take` operator will return **completed source** which will trigger our complete method inside the follow up subscribers (In our case inside the custom `test` operator and also inside the `subscribe` ) after that the `source` won't emit anything else, because it has already been completed.

You can check out the source => [take()](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/take.ts), for more information feel free to ask anything if there are some blurry parts.